# Bizzare results from a MySQL count(distinct) query

Tags: mysql

**Disclaimer:** This question was [rejected on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77351206/mysql-gone-mad-countdistinct-creates-weird-groups-duplicates) so I'm trying here. I think it might be better on topic here.

Here's a simple MySQL query that I tried to run <s>today</s> yesterday:

```
select
    year(payment_date) y,
    month(payment_date) m,
    count(distinct client_id) c
from payments
where payment_date > '2023-01-01'
group by y, m;
```

And the results are something like this (numbers anonymized):

| y | m | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 1 | 1234 |
| 2023 | 2 | 11 |
| 2023 | 1 | 67543 |
| 2023 | 2 | 11 |
| 2023 | 1 | 4456 |
| 2023 | 2 | 1 |
| 2023 | 1 | 78987 |
| 2023 | 2 | 1 |
| 2023 | 1 | 5678 |
| 2023 | 2 | 5555 |
| 2023 | 3 | 13 |
| 2023 | 2 | 9873 |
| 2023 | 3 | 16 |
| 2023 | 2 | 22564 |
| 2023 | 3 | 17 |
| 2023 | 2 | 99892 |
| 2023 | 3 | 1234 |
| 2023 | 4 | 2 |
| 2023 | 3 | 5678 |

What in the world happened here? Why are months duplicating and counts somehow split amongst them?

If I remove the `distinct` then the results look normal again, but that's not what I want.

If it's relevant, `payment_data` is of the type `timestamp` and the table is partitioned by it - however the partitions are each 1 month large (so even if it was displaying each partition separately for some reason, you still can't get more than 2 rows for each month).

`EXPLAIN` also says that it's using an index that consists of `(client_id, payment_date)`.

None of this should produce an obviously wrong result though.

I tried a few variations too:

```
select
    month(payment_date) m,
    count(distinct client_id) c
from payments
where payment_date > '2023-01-01'
group by m;
```

Still the same problem.

```
select
    date_format(payment_date, '%Y-%m') ym,
    count(distinct client_id) c
from payments
where payment_date > '2023-01-01'
group by ym;
```

Surprisingly, this works!

```
select
    cast(month(payment_date) as char) m,
    count(distinct client_id) c
from payments
where payment_date > '2023-01-01'
group by m;
```

And this works too!

```
select
    monthname(payment_date) m,
    count(distinct client_id) c
from payments
where payment_date > '2023-01-01'
group by m;
```

And this works as well.

Just in case it's relevant, here's a redacted view of the table definition. I've removed a bunch of columns and indexes that are not relevant here, but here's the juicy bits:

```
CREATE TABLE `payments` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `service_id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `client_id` mediumint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `payment_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-02-01 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`payment_date`),
  KEY `service_id` (`service_id`),
  KEY `client_id` (`client_id`,`payment_date`),
  KEY `payment_date` (`payment_date`),
  KEY `payment_date_primary` (`id`,`payment_date`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
PARTITION BY RANGE (unix_timestamp(`payment_date`))
(PARTITION p200501 VALUES LESS THAN (1104530400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p200502 VALUES LESS THAN (1107208800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p200503 VALUES LESS THAN (1109628000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p200504 VALUES LESS THAN (1112302800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p200505 VALUES LESS THAN (1114894800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p200506 VALUES LESS THAN (1117573200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p200507 VALUES LESS THAN (1120165200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 ... snip 260 rows ...
 PARTITION p202703 VALUES LESS THAN (1803852000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p202704 VALUES LESS THAN (1806526800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p202705 VALUES LESS THAN (1809118800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p202706 VALUES LESS THAN (1811797200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p202707 VALUES LESS THAN (1814389200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p_max VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB);
```

I cannot think of anything else I could provide because I honestly have no clue how this is even possible and what it might be related to. If there's some additional detail you'd like to know, I'll happily share it!

The server is MySQL 8.0.21.

Comment: I'm guessing if you remove the partitions query works as expected ? Long time ago this was listed as a [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44821) which was fixed. Maybe it is occurring again  in 8.0.21 version. Still you need to reproduce your issue with some data example, a small amount for each partition maybe

Comment: @ErgestBasha - Well, I'll try tomorrow, although no guarantees that it will succeed.